# Running a Java artifact downloaded from Maven in Gradle

Tags: maven, gradle

How would I run an artifact (say it is called A) I download from maven? This artifact has a run time dependencies on other maven artifacts. I got this to work using the JettyRun task. This involved having the source files for artifact A in the src/main/java directory. Assuming I don't have any source files (all my jars/dependencies are being retrieved from a maven repository), how would I start the Java program in artifact A using JettyRun or some other task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to start the server with the code shown below. I added a jar file to a local repository and then added a compile dependency to that jar as well as all of the other artifacts it's dependent on. The main thing was the classpath.

```
compileJava.enabled = false
task runServer(type:JettyRun){
  daemon = true
  classpath = sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
  httpPort = 8984
}
```

When I reach the end of build.gradle, the server stops running. Is there a way to keep the server live? I needed to set daemon to true because there were some tasks I need to execute after the server is started. However, once all of those tasks are complete, I need to keep the server up. How would I prevent the server from shutting down when the script finishes?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Jetty plugin allows you to point your project to a WAR file. Instead you could give the [Cargo plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-cargo-plugin) a shot. Here's a sample configuration:

```
cargo {
    containerId = 'jetty7x'
    port = 9090

    deployable {
        file = file('/your/path/A.war')
        context = 'yourcontext'
    }

    local {
        homeDir = file('/your/path/to/jetty-7')
    }
}
```